# Windows laptop going to sleep interrupts wifi for other users

Tags: wireless-networking, interrupts

I have two Windows 10 laptops in my house. When they are closed (sleep), they often interrupt the wifi for the rest of us on our phones or other devices. I've disabled network sharing on those two laptops as suggested by another article, but nothing fixes.

I have an Asus router and nothing is obvious in the system logs. Any suggestions on where to look to see what is causing the interruptions?

Comment: What makes you sure it's the laptops, and if there's two of them is it only when they are both asleep, one asleep etc?

Comment: I need to test to see if it happens with just one or both laptops. But it happens often enough when the laptops are put to sleep to point to that being the cause.